# XSL attirbutes with the same name

Tags: xslt

I am writing an xslt transformation for below XLS code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<OTA_HotelPmsInfoNotif xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" EchoToken="PMS" Version="0.101" PrimaryLangID="en" ClosureDate="2020-10-29" RetransmissionIndicator="true" SequenceNmbr="2" TimeStamp="2020-10-29T23:51:00Z">
  <POS>
    <Source>
      <RequestorID Type="81" ID="POF" ID_Context="parol"/>
    </Source>
    <Source ISOCountry="CZ" ISOCurrency="CZE">
      <RequestorID Type="10" ID="H1111" ID_Context="star">
        <CompanyName>Pharmacy Prague</CompanyName>
      </RequestorID>
    </Source>
  </POS>
</OTA_HotelPmsInfoNotif>
```

I would like to pull out of this XML attribute named ID but as you can see there are two ID attributes, ID="POF" and ID = "H1111". As for now i have what follows:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
  <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>RID</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>

    <xsl:for-each select="OTA_HotelPmsInfoNotif/POS/Source/RequestorID">
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:if test ="@ID='H1111'">
                <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:text>";"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this code enters one empty line for ID="POF". How to extract only one atrribute ID="H1111"?

Comment: What do you want as the output of your transformation?

Comment: I think you just need to put all your 3 <xsl:text> elements inside <xsl:if test ="@ID='H1111'">

Comment: You have 2 `RequestorID` elements with an `ID` attribute. If you want to get the value of `ID` only from one of the elements, you need to tell your stylesheet which one. IOW, you need to know something about the element that the stylesheet can use in order to find it - e.g. the `Type`.  Of course, if you know that the `ID` value is `H1111` then you don't need to get it; you can simply write it as is.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Based of what i have read i think i will use @Type to distinguish between two elements. Although i don't not how yet:)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the value of the `Type` attribute, you can do simply:

```
<xsl:value-of select="OTA_HotelPmsInfoNotif/POS/Source/RequestorID[@Type='10']/@ID"/>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/aiyndY